# How can I list what composer will autoload form the command line?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've created a new composer package which I want to autoload in my project. In my main `composer.json` at the project root I have:

```
{
    "require": {
        "league/oauth2-client": "0.7.*"
    },

  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "CC\\LinkedIn\\": "linkedin-extensions"
    }
  }
}
```

And in `/linkedin-extensions/composer.json` I have :

```
{
    "name": "root/linkedin-extensions",
    "description": "WP-OAuth extensions for LinkedIn",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "My Name",
            "email": "my@name.co.uk"
        }
    ],
    "require": {}
}
```

I then did `composer dumpautoload` and the autoloading appears to be working. Is there a way to verify this from the command line and output which namespaces/classes composer is aware of?

Answer (score 0):

One interesting utility that I discovered over the Christmas break is a visual dependency chart generator - https://github.com/clue/graph-composer

There is also the `--dry-run` option when you run composer, which checks what dependencies are required without actually installing them

Comment: This looks like the answer to a different question. This answer pertains to dependencies; he wants to list the classes that Composer can autoload.